# Is it possible to expand/collapes all panels in a region with a keystroke or shortcut?

Tags: python, interface

In particular, I'm looking for a simple way to collapse all the N and T panels.  I'm using a number of addons and things are starting to get a little cumbersome wheeling up and down to find something so I'd like to collapse them all at once and then expand just the one I want.

If not, is there an API that could make use of?

thanks

Comment: hovering over a collapsible region and pressing `A` toggles it, but I don't know about all at once.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on a panel header will close all other panels.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged with [python-api](/questions/tagged/python-api):

Currently the Python API can't handle opening and closing panels (it's possible but not exposed, in general Python scripts should not care about which panels are open).

Comment: If you only care about the panel's default state, it can be set with [`Panel.bl_options`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_options).

Comment: I get that it's not scene data, but it would be nice to be able to E.G. collapse hundreds of modifiers at once on hundreds of different objects so I can get an overview of which ones are enabled. Maybe the API could be write-only to prevent script behaviour from depending on panel state? (And I freely admit that is probably also a terrible idea for different reasons.)