# How do I get bookmarks to appear in 'fileselect' panel?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm a newbie to both Blender and Python so I'm not sure of the terms I use.

I have a number of button events that bring up the file select panel using

```
context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
```

when the panel is displayed on the right side I wish to see the
System (drives), Bookmarks and Recent files.

Is there a call I can make to have these displayed every time or
something else I need to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'have them displayed' they are always there, as far as I know, thought they may be in a collapsed panel. Not sure if there's a python API call to expand a specific panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to expand/collapes all panels in a region with a keystroke or shortcut?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/is-it-possible-to-expand-collapes-all-panels-in-a-region-with-a-keystroke-or-sho)